# Where can I view the Victory conditions in an online match in Civ 5?

Tags: civilization-5

A buddy of mine and I decided to finish a game we started a few months ago, but we cannot remember which victory conditions we manually set for this match against the AI.
**Where can we view this?**

Comment: My first instinct would be to check the Victory Progress screen, but I dunno if that shows disabled victory conditions or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Civ 5 Victory Progress screen (under the same menu where you access the Diplomacy Overview, etc.) only shows victory conditions that are active in the current game. Methods that are disabled will not even be displayed in the viewer.

(Source: Personal testing. A [new game of Civ V is created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obRkQ.jpg) with the Cultural and Diplomatic Victory conditions disabled. Once in the game, [the Victory Progress page is opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQKlI.jpg), showing only the Space, Domination, and Time Victory condition progress - the ones chosen at the beginning of the game.)

Comment: @Doomsknight I'm not quite sure I deserve it, given that it took the better part of a month to do so, but thank you. :)